# Get base url in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the base path of my Angular app.

Right now I'm doing this: `$scope.baseUrl = '$location.host()`

But I only get this: `/localhost`. My current baseURL is `http://localhost:9000/`.

Comment: You also need `$location.port()`

Comment: `absUrl()` probably ? Check: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: `$scope.baseUrl = $location.protocol() + "://" + location.host;`

Comment: this question was really useful for me today. Yay :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this: `$location.$$absUrl`

`console.log('$location',$location.$$absUrl);`

btw `/localhost` is your base path, but I guess you meant entire URL.

Comment: You should not be using properties & functions that begin with $$ instead find a supported angular way of doing it. E.g. using the absUrl() method

Answer (score 17):

An alternative answer is using the `$window` service in conjunction with `$location.absUrl()` to create a new URL object, and then grab the origin via the origin property. This will give you exactly what you're looking for (minus the trailing '/').

`$scope.baseUrl = new $window.URL($location.absUrl()).origin;` will give you back http://localhost:9000 in your case.

Answer (score 10):

To get just the baseurl and nothing else use

```
$browser.baseHref()
```

it will return something like

/central/

Comment: upvoted but this is private API and I prefer the result as http://someweb/somepath/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, `$location` doesn't provide what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 4):

A cross browser solution that worked for me was:

```
$location.$$absUrl.replace($location.$$url, '')
```

`$$absUrl` is the entire url (e.g. https://google.com/search/spiders)

`$$url` is the part after the host (e.g. /search/spiders)

Modify to taste.

Answer (score 3):

try injecting `$location` it has an `absUrl()` method on it that will return the entire current url

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the base url of the site, and not the current url of the page, e.g. from `https://www.google.com/somewhere/in-the-middle-of-nowhere` you want to get `https://www.google.com`, then simply do:

```
// For www.google.com
$scope.baseUrl = $locaton.$$host;
// For https://www.google.com
$scope.baseUrl = $location.$$protocol + '://' + $location.$$host;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$scope.baseUrl = '$location.host()`

Use this one :-

```
   $scope.baseUrl = $location.absUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late for the party, however I think `location.pathname` can be better.